# _co.photo is undefined console error and error context, but code works as expected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, frontend

I got problem with angular component.

When I make my component with selector, it works as expected: execute `httpget`, and render photo with title.
But in console I got two errors:

```
ERROR TypeError: "_co.photo is undefined"
    View_PhotoHolderComponent_0 PhotoHolderComponent.html:2
```

and

```
ERROR CONTEXT 
...
PhotoHolderComponent.html:2:8
    View_PhotoHolderComponent_0 PhotoHolderComponent.html:2
```

I got html:

```
    <div class="photo-holder">
    <h2>{{photo.title}}</h2>
    <img src="{{photo.url}}">
    </div>
```

and ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Photo } from './photo'
import { PhotoDeliveryService } from '../photo-delivery-service.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-photo-holder',
  templateUrl: './photo-holder.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./photo-holder.component.css']
})
export class PhotoHolderComponent implements OnInit {

  photo:Photo
  constructor( private photoService : PhotoDeliveryService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.photoService.getRandomPhoto().subscribe((data: Photo) => this.photo = {...data})
  }

}
```

and service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Photo } from './photo-holder/photo'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PhotoDeliveryService {
  value : Number
  url : string

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/";
    this.value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1; 
  }

  getRandomPhoto()  {
     return this.http.get<Photo>(this.getUrl())
  }

  getUrl(){
    return this.url + this.value;
  }

}
```

I suspect that could be made by binding property before query results was returned.
How can I rid off this problem, can I wait for this query, or this is different kind of problem ?

Comment: {{photo?.title}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because before your service could resolve, the template bindings are resolved and at that time photo object is undefined.

first thing, you can initialize the photo object but then you might have to detect the changes using ChangeDetectorRef to reflect the value returned by the service.

```
photo:Photo = {
    title:'',
    url:''
  };
  constructor( private photoService : PhotoserviceService, private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.photoService.getRandomPhoto().subscribe((data: Photo) => {
    this.photo =  data;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });
  }
```